# What is the difference between configuring SSL in nginx.conf or in sites-enabled?

Tags: ssl, nginx

I configured SSL in my nginx.conf. I'm getting a valid certificate on https://www.mydomain.com however, this shows a 404 as my website is at mydomain.com

Exploring, I see my site inside of available-sites which has a server block with a root and index but not listen block.

What is the difference between these two?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: Looks like many of the related questions with upvotes & comments are off-topic too. I asked on Server Fault, thanks.

Comment: @ quantumpotato - Yes, the best I can tell, nearly all of nginx questions are off-topic. I'm not sure why they are not migrated. Failure of the community, I suppose. I raised an issue on Meta, but no consensus was achieved. See [Review certain tags by default for eminent migration?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/222424/review-certain-tags-by-default-for-eminent-migration).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can place your SSL configuration into either file. If you check the bottom of `nginx.conf` you will see

```
include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
```

Which simply includes the contents of all config files in `sites-enabled` into `nginx.conf` and continues parsing.